# Is there a commonly accepted order of java class constructor overloadings?

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

I'm new to Java. I like to see the base constructor up front. But I have also seen a lot of code where the "base" constructor is placed last, after all the overloads. Is there a common practice on this regard?

```
class Foo {
    private int _var1;
    private long _var2;
    private float _var3;

    // the "base" constructor
    public Foo(int v1, long v2, float v3) {
        //......
    }

    public Foo(int v1, long v2) {
        this(v1, v2, 0f);
    }

    public Foo(int v1) {
        this(v1, 0L, 0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: The third could call the first (as you have), or the second via `this(v1, 0L)`. Calling the max-argument constructor (which could call `super(...)`) for each overload may be more revealing and helpful for the reader. What you have looks sufficient. Also, as others have noted, do not use a return type i.e. `void` in a constructor definition.

Comment: You do not have constructors in your code. These are overloaded methods.

Comment: To clarify PM 77-1's comment further, constructors do not define a return type -- they don't return anything at all

Comment: @Nexevis I see. Surely the first one is still a constructor though?

Comment: It is not.  `public foo(int v1, long v2, float v3)` _would_ be

Comment: Oh right.. my mistake. I should remove the `void` from method names. Will edit the question

Comment: I personally prefer the constructor with the smallest number parameters first, but this question is likely just opinion based

Comment: @Nexevis that's good to know as well! This question itself isn't opinion based, as if that's the case the answer is "No there isn't a universally agreed order" :)

Comment: These meta posts would disagree with you.  [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337031/primarily-opinion-based-on-best-practice-questions)

Comment: @Nexevis Let me rephrase the title to "Is there a ..." instead of "What's the best practice". The answer can be simply No. Anyway, while I don't agree with SO's philosophy on this (as seen in many comments in the linked metapost), feel free to close it if it violates the rule

Answer (score 1):

The convention in `java.*` classes is to have the simplest constructors first.

This means that someone using your class or reading your javadoc will probably find the constructor that they want/need earlier in the list, instead of filtering out all the more complex options.

As in `java.lang.String`:

```
String()
String(String original)
String(char[] value)
String(char[] value, int offset, int count)
String(int[] codePoints, int offset, int count)
String(byte[] ascii, int hibyte, int offset, int count)
String(byte[] ascii, int hibyte)
String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length, String charsetName)
etc.
```

So for `Foo` it would be, in order of increasing complexity:

```
Foo(int v1)
Foo(int v1, long v2)
Foo(int v1, long v2, float v3)
```